# Is there any way to remove item from PagedList and notify RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-paging

Is there any way to remove item from PagedList and notify RecyclerView without invalidating DataSource (not Room)?

**What I have tried:**

Store all model in own list, remove model from it when needed, call dataSource.invalidate() and submit stored list in loadInitial -> onResult callback.
But seems like this is not very elegant silution...

Comment: Have you tried to solve this on your own yet?

Comment: I have tried store all model in own list, remove a model from it when needed, call dataSource.invalidate() and submit stored list in loadInitial -> onResult callback.
But seems like this is not a very elegant solution...

Comment: Please add this to your question, you will get better results on this site if you indicate things that you have already tried.

Comment: The idea is that you have to invalidate the data source

Comment: Hey Vadaymj, I'm facing the same problem have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

After couple hours of trying my approach is call the network for removing and after collecting PagingData again. This action will go through till mapper.

```
 viewModel.remove(item) {
        lifecycleScope.launch{
            viewModel.uiState.collectLatest { uiState ->
               adapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, uiState.list)
            }
        }
```

And in the mapper check the field for me it was isUserFavorited. filter is a PagingDataTransforms extension and it was life saver other than visibility changing or layout height 0 shenanigans

```
return dataSource
        .myItemList(
            id = id,
            search = queryDecider.convertString(search),
        ).map {
            it.map { response ->
                mapper.map(response)
            }.filter { uiModel ->
                uiModel.isUserFavorited
            }
        }.flowOn(dispatcher.io)
```